# Autofill date in textbox in geckofx

Tags: winforms, fill, geckofx

I've been trying to fill some textboxes in geckofx 22.0.7. Most of them with success. There are a couple though that resist any change! Both of them allow only numbers to be typed.
 The first one (the one presented here) is used to receive a date entry. The user only types numbers (not slashes or dashes etc).
The html code follows:

```
<td class=" dataEntryCol4">
<input id="insertDate" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputmask ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="text" style="width:90px" tabindex="2" value="" name="insertDate" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
</td>
```

My code is this:

```
GeckoHtmlElement insertDate = document.GetHtmlElementById("insertDate");
insertDate.SetAttribute("value", "08/06/2014");
```

I also tried using

```
SendKeys.SendWait("08062014"); 
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
```

I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First cast GeckoHtmlElement to a GeckoInputElement then use the Value property.

```
GeckoInputElement insertDate = (GeckoInputElement)document.GetHtmlElementById("insertDate");
insertDate.Value = "08/06/2014";
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I had to add a "using Gecko.DOM" since I'm gonna use it a lot. One more thing... Do you have an explanation why my code wouldn't work? Similar code worked perfectly on webbrowser (IE). I've autofilled other input elements without using GeckoInputElement.